# How to sync a SharePoint List (via SP WebServices) with a SQL Table?

Tags: sharepoint, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

is there a possibility to sync a SharePoint list via standard SharePoint WebServices with a SQL Table? I would like to use the Microsoft Sync Framework. 
Some sample code would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Did you find any code sample for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Not much code samples, but SharePoint has APIs that works using Sync Framework. see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538641.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to work with SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services), an SSIS package using custom adapters from CodePlex may assist you.

MSDN Stub with links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh368261.aspx
CodePlex project: http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652